# Assemble multiple lists into a single list through a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

As part of an application reading Csv files made using tkinder and the tksheet library, I would have liked to ensure that each of the lines retrieved from my spreadsheet and individually transformed into a list could be grouped into a single and unique comma separated list.

I currently have the following code:

```py
with open('my_csv_file.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            
     for row in reader:
         if row != '' and row[0].isdigit():
            liste = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
            print(liste)
```

Output :

```
['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA']
['BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB']
['CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC']
```

What I want:

```
[['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA'],
['BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
['CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add list and append list in the list with  `list +=`

```
with open('my_csv_file.csv') as csvfile:
     res = []
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            
     for row in reader:
         if row != '' and row[0].isdigit():
            res += [[row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]]
```

or you can use `append`

```
with open('my_csv_file.csv') as csvfile:
     res = []
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            
     for row in reader:
         if row != '' and row[0].isdigit():
            res.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Append to the top list to make your nested list.

```
lst = []

with open('my_csv_file.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            
     for row in reader:
         if row != '' and row[0].isdigit():
            lst.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]])

print(lst)
```